# How to use constructor's method for an event listener

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, closures, prototype

So I'm working on OO Quiz app and I have Quiz constructor, which is supposed to launch the quiz app itself with all the questions and so on. First thing I want to do it is when user types his name and email and clicks the submit button, console.log his new created User object with name, email and so on in JSON string. I gave Quiz prototype a method `clickBtn` that checks whether the inputs are not empty and if are not, then  give me the JSON string.

After the method, I added event listener on a button and gave it not a random function but `prototype.clickBtn` method. Unfortunately, I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickBtn is not defined` error. What is the problem? Code snippet:

```
function Quiz (User, Question) {
  this.user = User;
  this.question = Question;
}

Quiz.prototype.constructor = Quiz;

Quiz.prototype.clickBtn = function () {
      if (theName.value == "") {
        var message = document.createElement("p");
        message.className = "message";
        message.innerHTML = "You forgot the name and email";
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(message);
      } else {
        var message = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0]; // first one
        message.parentNode.removeChild(message);
        console.log(message);
        var user1 = new User (theName.value, theEmail.value);
        users.push(user1);
        console.log("Quiz Created On: " + this.getQuizDate);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
      }
      theName.value = "";
      theEmail.value = "";
}

var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", clickBtn);
```

Comment: That is an utterly strange way to do things, especially since prototyping those methods don't really do anything without also creating **new** instances ?

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an instance of Quiz:

```
var quiz = new Quiz;
```

Then append your event listener as a method of your Quiz object.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", quiz.clickBtn);
```

Comment: Why we have to create new instance and cannot just say Quiz.clickBtn? Would it be syntaxically wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the clickBtn method of Quiz method, currently you are using clickBtn, but clickBtn is method of Quiz, so to access clickBtn, you need to call it with instance of Quiz method